# How to Update Query for Firebase UI recycler view adapter?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I am using Firebase UI for displaying data in recyler view from Firestore. Currently I am setting up the query and passing it to the recycler view once in the beginning. Now I want to apply some filter for which the query needs to be changed. I look at the official documentation and couldn't find something like that. I have followed this https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/firestore/README.md

This is what have done so far

```
 val query = db.collection("items")
        .whereEqualTo("inStock",true)
        .limit(10)

    val options = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ItemModel>()
        .setQuery(query, ItemModel::class.java)
        .setLifecycleOwner(this)
        .build()

    val adapter = FirestoreQuoteAdapter(options)
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
```

Based on user interaction, I would like to change Query to something like this, so that my recylcer view gets filtered according to the new query.

```
val query = db.collection("items")
        .whereEqualTo("inStock",false)
        .limit(10)
```

Can anyone please guide me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this update in my graddle and the updateOptions method became available. make sure in you gradle module app you have at least these versions or higher:

```
implementation'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:6.3.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:6.3.0'
```

then do this:

```
val newOptions = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ItemModel>()
    .setQuery(newQuery, ItemModel::class.java)
    .setLifecycleOwner(this)
    .build()
adapter.updateOptions(newOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update the options (including the query) of an existing `FirestoreReyclerAdapter` adapter by calling its [`updateOptions` method](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/d78e72bf12a7af9a7ae11f167764682b792f9c4b/firestore/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/firestore/FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.java#L104):

```
val newOptions = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ItemModel>()
    .setQuery(newQuery, ItemModel::class.java)
    .setLifecycleOwner(this)
    .build()
adapter.updateOptions(newOptions);
```

See this [branch](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/pull/1660) where the feature was added in July 2019.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have followed the link you have given and tried using the `updateOptions()` method on my `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`(the adapter as in my above post). But I see that there is no such method to be called on the adapter(The IDE shows text in red). Maybe I am doing some mistake? I wanted to post my code snippet for review but looks like that is not what comment is for?

Comment: Also why we don't have query updating feature mentioned in this offical doc? 
 https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/firestore .It would have helped a lot. Thanks

Comment: FirebaseUI is an open-source project, so if you think having that in the documentation would be helpful, the best thing you can do is to submit a pull request with the change.

Comment: Currently not capable enough for that but one day surely will :) Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do exactly what you are already doing now:

1. Create a new Query object
2. Provide it to a new instance of FirestoreRecyclerAdapter
3. Add the adapter to the recyclerview

You can't replace the query inside an existing adapter - you have to create a whole new adapter.  You can reuse the existing RecyclerView or not - it's up to you.