# How can I get an order id from Firestore and pass it to my adaptor class?

Tags: java, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, nullpointerexception

I need to get an order id from Firestore and pass that id to my Query but I'm getting the order id happens asynchronously. So I am forced to initialize my adaptor inside the Firebase callback method. The issue is that my onStart and onStop methods are listening on the adaptor and then throws a NullPointException.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_to_cart);

        // Navigate to men section
        fromAddToCartToForHim = findViewById(R.id.fromAddToCartToForHim);
        fromAddToCartToForHim.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(AddToCart.this, HimActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });


        //Navigate to Women section
        fromAddToCartToForHer = findViewById(R.id.fromAddToCartToForHer);
        fromAddToCartToForHer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(AddToCart.this, WomenActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });


        // Navigate to Household section

        fromAddToCartToForHouseHold = findViewById(R.id.fromAddToCartToForHouseHold);
        fromAddToCartToForHouseHold.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(AddToCart.this, HouseHoldActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });


        // SetUpRecyclerView func

        setUpRecycleView();


    }
```

```
private void setUpRecycleView() {


        // GET CURRENT ORDER ID

        orderRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull @NotNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isComplete()) {

                    QuerySnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();

                    assert snapshot != null;
                    for (DocumentSnapshot snapshots : snapshot.getDocuments()) {

                        String user_id = snapshots.getString("user_id");
                        Boolean status = snapshots.getBoolean("status");

                        if (user_id.equals(getUserId()) && !status) {

                            // User has existing Order
                            // Check if order is pending or completed

                            String orderId = snapshots.getId();

                            Query query = orderRef
                                    .document(orderId)
                                    .collection("orderlist")
                                    .orderBy("category").orderBy("priority", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);

                            FirestoreRecyclerOptions<OrderList> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<OrderList>()
                                    .setQuery(query, OrderList.class)
                                    .build();


                            addToCartAdaptor = new AddToCartAdaptor(options);

                            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewAddToCart);
                            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(AddToCart.this));
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(addToCartAdaptor);
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
        });
    }
```

```
enter code here

 @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        addToCartAdaptor.startListening(); Error happens here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {   `enter code here`
        super.onStop();

        addToCartAdaptor.stopListening();
    }
```

HERE IS THE ERROR I GET

```
W/example.neptun: Accessing hidden method Lcom/msic/qarth/PatchStore;->createDisableExceptionQarthFile(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)Z (blacklist, JNI)
E/example.neptun: [qarth_debug:]  get PatchStore::createDisableExceptionQarthFile method fail.
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.neptune, PID: 2884
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.neptune.Adapters.AddToCartAdaptor.startListening()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.neptune.AddToCart.onStart(AddToCart.java:150)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1419)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7479)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3454)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2884 SIG: 9
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Besides that, please also indicate the exact line at which the error occurs.

Comment: The error I am getting is pointing to the onStart function where I have the addToCartAdaptor.startListening()

Comment: Please edit your question and show us where in your code are you calling setUpRecycleView().

Comment: I am calling setUpRecyclerView from onCreate method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using the following line of code:

```
addToCartAdaptor = new AddToCartAdaptor(options);
```

Inside the "onComplete()" method, it means it will always run right after the onStart, as it takes some time to get the data from the `orderRef` reference. What you can do, is to create the (default) Query, FirestoreRecyclerOptions, and AddToCartAdaptor objects outside the onComplete() method, and once you get the data inside the callback, simply update the "options" object, with the data that you get from the database. In this way, you provide the data to the "options" object, only when it is available.

This also means that you'll never get a NullPointerException anymore because the `addToCartAdaptor` is already initialized.

Comment: This solves the issue of nullpointer on the part of the adaptor however, there is a relationship between Query, FirestoreRecyclerOptions, and AddToCartAdaptor in the sense that Query.document(?) needs an orderId which comes from the onComplete method. Since this is Async I cannot use that data outside the method

Comment: That's what I was talking about. Pass a default instance of a Query the first time to instantiate the "options" object, and once you get the data from the database, create a new Query object, containing the (`orderId`), and then pass that Query to the "options" object using updateOptions() method like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67097540/5246885), right?

Comment: Hi, Alex using your suggestions above works forme thank you. However, there's still a problem. The recyclerview only displays items from firestore once I minimize the app and maximize it again.

Comment: Good to hear that it worked. Hmm, there might be a lot of reasons why you get that behavior but without seeing the code, I cannot be much of a help. So please post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.